# Conditional Formatting based on choice selection from another column

Tags: json-formatting

I'm new to SharePoint List Conditional Formatting

I've got two columns one is [$Status], and the other is Due Date. If the status is resolved it will be green,

if the status is open and the due date is before  @now then red
if the status is open and the due date is after @now then yellow
if the status is open and the due date is same as @now then yellow.

I currently have this, but I'm unsure of how to add those If statements. Any help would be appreciated! I have the following JSON code right now:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding": "0 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            ""
          ]
        },
        "",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@now"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@currentField"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@now"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": ">",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@currentField"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like below

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Resolved', '#008000', if([$DueDate] < @now , '#ff0000',if([$DueDate] > @now, '#FFFF00', '#00FF00')))"
  }
}
```

In my example, [DueDate] is the Date column and '[Status]' is a Choice column with 2 values 'Open' and 'Resolved' and this formatting is done in 'Status' column.

Please check the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) for detailed reference.

Here is the one with your version:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding": "0 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "Resolved"
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
               "[$DueDate]",
                "@now"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                   "operands": [
                      "[$DueDate]",
                      "@now"
                    ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": ">",
                      "operands": [
                          "[$DueDate]",
                          "@now"
                        ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```